# Round time to the nearest 30 min using moment.js #javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I would like to round to the nearest 30 mins with moment.js, Below is my current code which doesn't work at the moment. Maybe i don't have the right moment.js syntax. When I use the normal Date object from javascript it works fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="moment-with-locales.js">


var jetzt = moment().format('lll');
jetzt.seconds(0);
jetzt.milliseconds(0);
var minuten = jetzt.minutes();
var minutenToAdd = 0;
if (minuten >= 0 && minuten <= 29)
{
    minutenToAdd = 30 - minuten;
}
else if (minuten >= 31 && minuten <= 59)
{
    minutenToAdd = 60 - minuten;
}
var MIN_IN_MS = 60000;
var HALF_HOUR_IN_MS = 3600000;

minutenToAdd = minutenToAdd * MIN_IN_MS;
var Datum = moment(jetzt.moment() + minutenToAdd).format('lll');
alert(Datum);




</script>
```

thx for help :)

Comment: Why do you call `jetzt.seconds(0);` twice in a row?

Comment: Does this even run without throwing errors right away? The return value of the `format` method is a string, is it not? Then you should get an error for all the methods you are trying to call on `jetzt` afterwards here, because a string object has none of those.

Comment: @A.A. edited. milliseconds

Comment: @04FS no errors nothing happens right now. no alert window shown.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/n0kv2mxc/ shows exactly what was to be expected in the browser console - _“Uncaught TypeError: jetzt.seconds is not a function”_

Comment: u have to bind the moment.js from the internet

Comment: I did, look closely, it is under Resources in the left side panel. And if the moment library was not embedded,  it would have thrown an error on `var jetzt = moment().format('lll');` already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var jetzt = moment().format('lll');
```

This returns a *string*, you can not call moment methods on a string object. So this needs to be just

```
var jetzt = moment();
```

And here

```
var Datum = moment(jetzt.moment() + minutenToAdd).format('lll');
```

the `jetzt.moment()` needs to be replaced by just `jetzt` then - it is a moment instance already (now.)

https://jsfiddle.net/n0kv2mxc/1/